# urllib2 bypassing cloudflare

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, cloudflare

I have wrote a script to grab the data from a php file on a website. I wrote the script so that it only outputs the data if the current data on the page has changed from what it was the last time it grabbed data from the page. The page does require authentication, which is why I have the PHPSESSID added in. That will allow the page to be viewed. Cloudflare has been implemented

Checking your browser before accessing website.com.

This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.
Please allow up to 5 seconds...

This has broken my script and it is unable to grab the data from the page. I looked at cfscrape and can't figure out how to implement it into my current script to get it to work. If anyone could provide assistance that would be awesome! I hate having to reach out for help, but I kinda need to have this functioning as soon as possible.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from time import sleep
import re
import hashlib
import urllib2
import winsound

def doMd5(data):
    mdo = hashlib.md5()
    mdo.update(data)
    return mdo.hexdigest()

def doRequest():
    try:
        head = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
                'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=ldc1bp9mj7n4ocffvftm25te62'}
        req = urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com/random/random.php', headers=head)
        res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        data = res.read()
        return data
    except:
        return "exception"

last_log = ""

while True:
    data = doRequest()

    if data == "exception" or data == "":
        print "Exception!"
        continue

    new_hash = doMd5(data)

    if new_hash != last_log:
        print "New Data"
        winsound.Beep(100, 80)

            handler = open('data.html', 'a')
            handler.write(data + '\n')
            handler.close()

            last_log = new_hash
    else:
        sleep(3)
        print "Refreshing..."
        continue
```

Comment: Replace all urllib usage with [cfscape usage](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape#usage)... All you need to do is get the website content, right?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of CloudFlare's "detecting your browser" page is, essentially, to block bots.

It's working correctly here. You will need to ask the owner of the web site to disable this protection for their site, or to make an exception for you.

Comment: Thanks captain obvious!